# Tag which would mean "a part of the question needs to be translated."

Tags: feature-request, tags

Я бажаю поставити моє питання українською. Але, я не дуже добре розмовляю українською, і тому деякі частини мого питання я не знаю як перекласти на українську мову. Я propose a tag, який би позначав, що треба correct моє питання за правильним перекладом деяких слів на українську мову.

Якщо хтось поправить моє питання, то йому можна дати тих два points, які зазвичай даються за поліпшення питання або відповіді.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks. IMHO, good idea.

It's actually even not a feature request — we don't need a support from outside for it; it could be our local community tags and agreement about them.

I propose the following tag names:

- `help-me-into-ukr` — tag that asks/allows community to edit specific question by translating untranslated parts into Ukrainian;
- `help-me-into-eng` — tag that asks/allows community to edit specific question by translating untranslated parts into English (e.g. for the meta section and for some rare cases).

What we should do:

1. Agree about names (the above two are just a proposition).
2. Create them (everybody can create a new tag when creates a question).
3. Write guidance/description for them (anybody can propose a guidance and a description, but moderator or somebody with high reputation needs to approve it).
4. Create question/answer within meta that *clearly* describes these tags (or turn **this** question/answer into such informational page).
5. Use it freely.

These tags don't impose any specific obligations, give any specific right or any additional bonus, they just:

- clearly declare the intent of the question author (*I would be glad if somebody translates untranslated parts of my question into Ukr/Eng*);
- simplifies search of such questions; for example for somebody who likes to do such translations and wants to see a list of awaiting-for-translation questions.

Issues:

- Probably a translator should also remove these tags when saving edited question, shouldn't he? (I.e. to make search results for `[help-me-into-???]`  to include only questions awaiting for translation, not together with already translated.) Or should he just add some extra tag like `already-translated` when saving an edited question (so that search result for more complex query `[help-me-into-ukr] -[already-translated]` will show only untranslated questions)?
- What if a translator misinterprets original translation text, making the question text wrong after translation? (Personally I consider that as not so awful. History is saved. The question author or anybody else can revert/fix if he sees a bad translation. A question author who puts the `help-me-into-???` tag realizes/accepts the risks related to incorrect translation.)

Comment: Yeah, these were exactly the pro's that I was thinking about when I asked this.  I guess I just didn't think of listing them for everyone.  My suggestion of how to address the issues will follow below.  Let me know your opinion.

Comment: When a translation is done, the tag should be removed.  No benefit of keeping it.

Comment: If a translator misinterprets the original text, then either the original poster will see it, and deny the edit (usually, people who speak only Russian can still understand Ukrainian)-- or else it will require the approval of two high-rep people--- who, in turn, will note the discrepancy, and deny the edit.

Comment: This looks like a nice idea. The problem is that many new users do not read the guidelines about using tags. So there's a chance that this technique will stay unused even if we define it.

Comment: @bytebuster, at least, it doesn't create problems for those who don't know about it / don't use it. (I.e. who wants — uses, who doesn't — doesn't.)

Comment: Sorry for noob question, but does user get some notification that his/her post was edited? Can he/she see changes? If not, I think it will be more useful to write out mistakes in comments so that asker can learn...

Comment: @KyryloYatsenko, yes, every user (not only original author) can see the whole change history (by clicking on the “edited at …” link below any question/answer that was edited at least once, e.g. [here](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/171/4)). Yes, AFAIK, (successful) editing of somebody's post causes him to receive notification.